# python: increasing speed of using a list to search an input file

Tags: python, search

I have a list (inst_list) that consists of 20k elements and an input file (netlistFile) that is roughly 20k lines. Right now I have written two for loops where for each element in the list I search the input file. However, this is taking about 16 minutes to run because of the size of both files.

My coding abilities are very low, so there must be a faster way of doing it. Below is my code:

```
for x in inst_list:
    count = 0
    for line in fileinput.input(netlistFile):
        if re.search(x,line) and count != 1:
            #print line
            line_split = line.split(" ")
            cell_list.append(line_split[3])
            count = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need regex?  Could you just use `if x in line`?

Comment: If you *do* have to use a regex it might be better to compile one.

Comment: Also, could you explain a little better what you're actually doing?  There's a chance you might be able to get a *much* more optimized solution using a `set` or a `dict`

Comment: It also doesn't appear that you need `fileinput` here.  You should be able to just open your file object and iterate which would probably be more efficient.  Finally, if we knew what the lines looked like, we might be able to come up with a more efficient solution based on sorting (if there's any pattern to the lines).

Comment: Biggest optimization here would be to load the file into memory *before* your `for` loops. File IO is relatively expensive as far as time goes.

Comment: or just swap the loops.  right now you're reading the file many times; just read it once, and on each line, check for each of your search terms before continuing.

Comment: `fileinput` doesn't slow anything down other than a tiny constant term. Reading the whole file at once and iterating its lines is probably _slower_ than iterating the line (remember that I/O is buffered). Compiling or eliminating a regex might cut the time in half or something, but it's not going to fix his minutes-when-it-should-be-seconds problem. The keys pretty much have to be: only read the file once as Eevee suggested, and convert something (it's not clear what without more info…) into a `set` (or `dict` or `blist.sortedlist` or whatever), as mgilson suggested.

Comment: As @abarnert suggested, we are talking about [big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The problem with using the two for loops is that it is O(n^2). Some sort of sorting or hashing `dict` or `list` would have to be used to beat that. Exactly which algorithm is used would depend on how the `dict` or `list` could be organized.

Comment: Something that may probably reduce the constants in that code's complexity is loading the whole text into memory as a string and let the regexes check the whole file(you'll probably have to change the regexes so that they they search the beginning of lines). This transforms python-level for-loops into C-level loops over strings which are usually much, much faster[even though it's still O(n^2)]
Anyway, you may be able to avoid regexes at all, in which case, as other already suggested, you may be able to do it in less than O(n^2) using other data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix was to just switch the loops like @Eevee suggested in the comments.